# Equivalent of overflow visible on grid row xaml windows 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows

I have a list box that appears only when you click a button. The problem is, the listbox is cut off at the bottom as it is taller than the grid row it sits in. It needs to pop out of the grid when displayed.

In CSS, this could be done with adding "overflow:visible" to the parent grid row, but I've been searching all morning and can't find anything quite the same! Does anyone have a solution?!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: share you code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Callisto control library

https://github.com/timheuer/callisto

There is a `Flyout` control that is perfect for your needs

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dean. I managed to solve it using popup, but that library will definitely be useful for other stuff. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by adding a  tag around the listbox, which pulled it out of the row. It still positioned correctly, too, which was a bonus!

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
    <Listbox ... />
</Popup>
```

Hope this helps someone!